# How to parse .dvi file in c#. Reading 24 word int in C# is my problem

Tags: dvi

I try to read .dvi file in c#. I have a problem with the 3 word or 24 byte integer.

How do I do the HiLo field swapping on this, .NET is in little endian and i believe .dvi is in big endian. And the 24 byte integer is slightly unique.

My goal is to read it to a 32 byte int type with 2's complement handling.

My goal is to read the dvi and the \special{} as extensions from TeX.

But to get the \special out and handle it in code seems to require to parse the whole dvi binary. To do this I already have tif and gf files in parsed.

Comment: Did you check out https://ctan.org/pkg/dvitype ?

Comment: I guess you also checked out https://git.cgsecurity.org/cgit/testdisk/tree/src/file_dvi.c http://tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html#gftodvi-invocation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_file_format#References_and_notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is more about C# than about the DVI format (and so more appropriate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)), but let me answer anyway. Yes, the integers in the DVI format are indeed big-endian. To read the 24-bit (or 3-byte) integers, you can just read them byte-by-byte and perform the arithmetic yourself: for example, if `r` is such that `r.ReadByte()` gives the next byte, in range 0–255 (and advances the position), then you can read a 24-bit integer with:

```cs
(r.readByte() * 256 + r.readByte()) * 256 + r.readByte()
```

I think that answers your question, but just for completeness, and to illustrate how simple the DVI format is (see [1](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/texware/dvitype.pdf#page=7), [2](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=213), [3](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb03-2/tb06software.pdf#page=2), [4](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb13-1/tb34dvistd.pdf), or [5](http://mirrors.ctan.org/dviware/driv-standard/level-0/dvistd0.pdf)), here is a complete C# program that parses an entire DVI file and writes out only the DVI specials. (The output has been verified against that of `dvitype foo.dvi | grep xxx` which is a simple Unix pipeline to get the same.) It can easily be extended to do more if necessary.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace DviSpecials {
  class Program {
    // Reads from |r| an integer (big-endian) that is |length| bytes long.
    static int ReadInt(BinaryReader r, int length) {
      int n = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) n = n * 256 + r.ReadByte();
      return n;
    }
    // Reads a DVI special command (xxx1 to xxx4) 
    static byte[] ReadSpecial(Byte op, BinaryReader r) {
      if (!(239 <= op && op <= 242)) throw new Exception("Not a special");
      int k = ReadInt(r, op - 238);
      return r.ReadBytes(k);
    }
    // Returns the list of bytes for one DVI command.
    // (Actually, drops info for fnt_def; interface needs to change.)
    static List<byte> ReadOneCommand(BinaryReader r)
    {
      // Commands that take no (so 0 bytes of) additional parameters.
      byte[] commands0 = { 
        // other than set_char 0 to 127 and fnt_num 171 to 234
        138, 140, 141, 142, 147, 152, 161,
      };
      // Commands that take 1,2,...,44 additional bytes of parameters respectively.
      byte[] commands1 = { 128, 133, 143, 148, 153, 157, 162, 167, 235 };
      byte[] commands2 = { 129, 134, 144, 149, 154, 158, 163, 168, 236 };
      byte[] commands3 = { 130, 135, 145, 150, 155, 159, 164, 169, 237 };
      byte[] commands4 = { 131, 136, 146, 151, 156, 160, 165, 170, 238 };
      byte[] commands8 = { 132, 137 };
      byte[] commands44 = { 139 };
      // Undefined commands.
      byte[] commandsUd = { 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255 };

      List<byte> ret = new List<byte> { r.ReadByte() };
      byte b = ret[0];
      if (b <= 127 || (171 <= b && b <= 234) || commands0.Contains(b)) return ret;
      if (commands1.Contains(b)) ret.Add(r.ReadByte());
      if (commands2.Contains(b)) ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(2));
      if (commands3.Contains(b)) ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(3));
      if (commands4.Contains(b)) ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(4));
      if (commands8.Contains(b)) ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(8));
      if (commands44.Contains(b)) ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(44));
      if (commandsUd.Contains(b)) throw new Exception("Undefined command");
      if (239 <= b && b <= 242) ret.AddRange(ReadSpecial(b, r));
      if (243 <= b && b <= 246) {
        // fnt_def k[1-4] c[4] s[4] d[4] a[1] l[1] n[a + l]
        int k = ReadInt(r, b - 242);
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(12));
        int a = r.ReadByte();
        int l = r.ReadByte();
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(a + l));
      }
      if (b == 247) { // pre: i[1] num[4] den[4] mag[4] k[1] x[k]
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(13));
        int k = r.ReadByte();
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(k));
      }
      if (b == 248) { // post: p[4] num[4] den[4] mag [4] l[4] u[4] s[2] t[2]
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(28));
      }
      if (b == 249) { // post_post: q[4] i[1] 223s[>=4]
        ret.AddRange(r.ReadBytes(5));
        if (r.BaseStream.Length < r.BaseStream.Position + 4) {
          throw new Exception("Expecting DF at least 4 times");
        }
        while (r.BaseStream.Position != r.BaseStream.Length) {
          if (r.ReadByte() != 223) throw new Exception("Expecting 0xDF");
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }

    static int Main(string[] args) {
      if (args.Length == 0) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Please pass a DVI file as argument.");
        return 1;
      }
      String filepath = args[0];
      using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open)) {
        using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs)) {
          while (r.BaseStream.Position != r.BaseStream.Length) {
            long pos = r.BaseStream.Position;
            List<byte> bs = ReadOneCommand(r);
            byte op = bs[0];
            if (239 <= op && op <= 242) {
              // Assumes the special is a UTF8 string. Change for arbitrary bytes.
              var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bs.Skip(1).ToArray());
              Console.WriteLine($"{pos}: xxx '{s}'");
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

For more questions about the DVI format, apart from the links above, you can look at the source code of programs like DVItype, dvipng, dvi2bitmap, or [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/) (the last may be best, as it's actively maintained and supports many extensions to DVI such as XeTeX's `xdv`).